# Get number of instance of text "x" in word list

Tags: c#, regex, list, instance

I'm working c# to find out number of instances of exact word of "x". For example:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>  {"Mode", "Model", "Model:", "Generator (1100)", "(1100)", "13Generator"}; 
Text = "This is Model: x Type: Model: y aa: Mode e Model: Generator (1100) (1100) 13Generator";
var textArray = Text.Split(' ');
var count = words.Select(item => textArray.ToList().Contains(item) ? 
             textArray.Count(d => d == item) : 0).ToArray();
```

I've used Regex:

```
List<int> count = new List<int>();
foreach (var word in words)
{
    var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}(\s|$)", word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    count.Add(regex.Matches(Text).Count);
}
```

I want the count to be:
{1,0,3,1,2,1)
I don't want to use split in my case. So, is there any way I can get not using split?

{ "Mode", "Model", "Model:" }; are perfeclty working, but Generator (1100), (1100) are not working. I want all "Mode", "Model:", "Generator (1100)", "(1100)", and "13Generator" to work.

It would be great if someone can help me.
Thank you,

Comment: Could you clarify what a *word* means here? All the strings in `words`? Tried `string.Format(@"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w)", word)`? I get `1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1` as a result in `count`, is it OK?

Comment: What `{0}` is it for?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your input data, you need to be able to match your strings as whole words irrespective of what type the first and last characters are in your `words` items.

I sugggest using unambiguous word boundaries `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`:

```
var words = new List<string> { "Mode", "Model", "Model:", "Generator (1100)", "(1100)", "13Generator" };
var count = new List<int>();
var Text = "This is Model: x Type: Model: y aa: Mode e Model: Generator (1100) (1100) 13Generator";
foreach (var word in words)
{
    var reg = string.Format(@"(?<!\S){0}(?!\S)", Regex.Escape(word));
    // Or, in C#6.0
    // var reg = $@"(?<!\S){Regex.Escape(word)}(?!\S)";
    count.Add(Regex.Matches(Text, reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count);
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", count));
count.Add(Regex.Matches(Text, reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count);
// => 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/2d0LFV)

The `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` lookarounds make sure the word is neither preceded nor followed with non-whitespace characters.

Escaping the special characters is required for the parentheses (and the like) to be matched as literal symbols.

Comment: Hi, 
This looks good however, I want "Model"= 0 and (1100) = 1 because I want to be pass only when the word is exactly matched. In other words I want => 1,0,3,1,1,1

Comment: Your input string contains 3 whole words `Model`: *This is **Model**: x Type: **Model**: y aa: Mode e **Model**: Generator (1100) (1100) 13Generator*. What do you mean by *exactly matched*? Besides, there are 2 instances of **(1100)** in your string, how can you only get 1?

Comment: When you iterate through the words in `words`, the `(1100)` item does not know the previous one was `Generator (1100)`. You need to formulate the requirements more clearly.

Comment: Oh thats my bad. Yes (1100) should be two. However, since there is no "Model" the word without ":" I want Model = 0 and "Model:" = 3. 
Thank you.

Comment: Then, you need to make sure `Model` does not match `Model:`. This can be done manually by providing a list of *patterns* inside `words`: `var words = new List<string> { "Mode(?!l:?)", "Model(?!:)", "Model:", @"Generator \(1100\)", @"\(1100\)", "13Generator" };` and then use `var reg = string.Format(@"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w)", word);`

Comment: Is there anyway we can do it by modifying var reg=string.Format(),word only? because I'm getting the words list from other source (string file).

Comment: That will require some coding. I will look through what I have.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. 
I appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like requiring the absence of non-whitespace characters around your keywords gives the expected results. Please confirm. If not, some more coding I mentioned is necessary (and I have not found anything related to that so far :()

Answer (score 0):

Some of your target sequences contain special regex characters. For example, parentheses inside

```
Generator (1100)
```

will be interpreted as delimiters of a *capturing group*, not as literal parentheses. These characters need to be properly escaped. Regular expressions library provides an [`Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that:

```
// This uses C# 6 interpolated strings instead of string.Format:
var regex = new Regex(@$"\b{Regex.Escape(word)}(\s|$)"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Once the word is escaped, you could proceed with a search on the original string without a split.

Comment: If I use only var regex = new Regex(@$"\b{Regex.Escape(word)}\b"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);, I got Model = 3 instead of 0. Is there anyway I can get exact same word?
Thank you.

Comment: Because OP needs to create a list of patterns that do not match one another (based on some external source).

Comment: @user3284302 Replacing `\b` with `(\s|$)` from your original expression should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    words.Select(w => 
                 new { 
                      Word = w, 
                      Count = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b" + w.Replace(" ",@".+\s+.") + @"\b").Count 
                     })
         .Where(o => o.Count > 0).ToList()
         .ForEach(o => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ===> {1} occurence(s)", o.Word, o.Count)));
```

Output:

```
Mode ===> 1 occurence(s)
Model ===> 3 occurence(s)
Generator (1100) ===> 1 occurence(s)
(1100) ===> 2 occurence(s)
13Generator ===> 1 occurence(s)
```